# Private key is not installed in MAC

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, application-loader

I am trying to validate my app after archive in xcode. But it throughs error like[image]

I am using mac for first time and dont know what is happening.
CAn somebody please ans the question. (I have searched a lot but no ans)

Comment: "Contact the creator of one of these certificate to get a copy of the private key" is a pretty good error message :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly saying 'distribution' private key is missing. [image]

for the red marked certificate. Whoever created the distribution certificate will be having the private key in their key chain. get the certificate and private key (both selected)export as .p12 file. remove the current public certificate and import the exported file into keychain

Comment: @RajanLagah that you are saying is the `development` certificate, there must be a `distribution` certificate along with private key like the same as `development`. And yes, it must be with same team ID

Comment: @Sulthan yes, may be. But I was getting an error on importing the certificate and private key from .p12 file, since the certificate(public key) was already there in keychain.

Comment: @Sulthan sarath is there any way i can change that and direct it to that(H2U...) one?